# Can't catch exceptions with ...catch( \Exception $e ){... in PHP/Lumen 8.x

Tags: php, lumen-8

I'm working on a PHP/Lumen 8.x foreach loop to manage the update/insert of records from a mysql DB table in which I'm trying to catch any errors during the update/insert process so that it can continue with subsequent logs in case of error. As I am with Lumen and we are in a certain namespace environment in the catch statement I use "\Exception" to identify the type of exception. However, in no case in which an error occurs can I catch it and in the controller output, that is, in the controller response, an error indicating "Recursion detected" is triggered. I can't catch this last error either.

This is the code snippet for the foreach(...) { ... try..catch ...} block:

```
foreach($prdsData as $prod){

    $cr_sku = $prod['SKU'];

    try{

        $res_prod_uc[$cr_sku]['err'] = false;

        $res_prod_uc[$cr_sku]['res'] = wc_product_update($pd);

    } catch( \Exception $e ){

        $res_prod_uc[$cr_sku]['err'] = true;

        $cr_err_dt = array(
                        'code'  => $e->getCode(),
                        'msg'   => $e->getMessage(),
                        'file'  => $e->getFile(),
                        'line'  => $e->getLine(),
                        'trace' => $e->getTrace()
                    );

        $res_prod_uc[$cr_sku]['err_data'] = $cr_err_dt;

        continue;
    }
}

return response()->json($res_prod_uc,200); // this is where the "Recursion detected" error is triggered
```

This is the output (JSON) of the "Recursion detected" error:

```
{
    "message": "Recursion detected",
    "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",
    "file": "..../blog/vendor/illuminate/http/JsonResponse.php",
    "line": 88,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "..../blog/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/JsonResponse.php",
            "line": 54,
            "function": "setData",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "..../blog/vendor/illuminate/http/JsonResponse.php",
            "line": 32,
            "function": "__construct",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\JsonResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "..../blog/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Http/ResponseFactory.php",
            "line": 40,
            "function": "__construct",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        
        /* this is my controller */
        {
            "file": "..../blog/app/Http/Controllers/ProductsController.php", 
            "line": 145,
            "function": "json",
            "class": "Laravel\\Lumen\\Http\\ResponseFactory",
            "type": "->"
        },....
```

How can I go about catching any errors?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your response is outside of the catch block, so it won't be caught. You can add the response to it's own try/catch block, and return something basic if it fails. Otherwise, I'd figure out why it's throwing the error and figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Yes, the curious thing is that if I remove the try..catch the error "Recursion detected" does not occur

Comment: It's probably something you're doing inside of the catch block. You're adding a lot of data to the error key, and it may be something in there. Or it could be the way you're building the array. I would probably suggest removing the `'trace' => $e->getTrace()` at the very least

Comment: @aynber That is the source of the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was happening is exactly what you say @aynber. I did check and, yes, exceptions are being cached, but the line `'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString()` does indeed allocate data where at deeper levels there is object recursion. And by the time the thread reaches `return response()->json($res,200);` (Which is outside of the try..catch block) the "Recursion detected" error is raised. This error is generated by a call to the json_encode() PHP function found within the Lumen 8 framework.

The solution I used was to replace the getTrace() method with the getTraceAsString() Exception object method.